Prove that $f$ is not one-to-one on the interval.
Let $f$ be a continuous function on the interval $[0, \infty)$ such that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = f(0)
$$
Prove that $f$ is not one-to-one on the interval $[0, \infty)$.
Hint: It may be helpful to separate into two cases: $f$ is constant on the interval, $f$ is not constant on the interval.
I'm feeling incredibly lost in this course. No matter how much time I dedicate to studying, I can't seem to grasp the concepts. I'm currently facing an assignment that has me completely stumped, and I don't even know where to start.
How to get started with these questions? I'm losing it.
Thank you.

Do you know the intermediate value theorem? It will be helpful here.

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty]$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and is bijective on its domain. Are you missing some hypotheses?

I'm not going to say much since you're not showing any attempt. But drawing a picture could be helpful; and what Joe said.

@CSquared the limiting value is $f(0)$, not $0$ itself.

@CSquared In your example, the limit dies not equal $f(0)$, but that's required in the problem.

To address your feelings of despair: this is natural. “Learning is the temporary interruption of confusion.” Bring your questions to your professor and TA—this is their job. And when you are lost, retrace your steps. Go back to the point in the text or notes where you were last confident, and take small steps from there.

@Joe Yes, this question is part of a questions that related to this theorem.
I'll try that, thank you.
C Squared: I copied the question as it appears. I don't know about anything I missed (of course I checked). -only updated techincal problem, [0,∞] => [0,∞)
paw88789: Maybe I'm not showing that here, but I really tried to understand that- and as I said, I don't even know where to start.
Sassatelli Giulio: Thank you.
Lieven: Sorry, technical mistake. [0,∞] => [0,∞)

@Matthew Leingang Thank you so much. I was hoping to get responses like these that help with the feelings of hopelessness, but I didn't expect it to actually come through here. This really helps me.

Consider $f(1)$. If it's equal to $f(0)$, then we're done. If it's not equal to $f(0)$, then it's either bigger or smaller; let's tackle both cases at once.
Given that $f(1) \neq f(0)$, we know from the hypotheses on continuity and the limit that, eventually, the function will come back down (or up) to the midpoint of $f(1)$ and $f(0)$, i.e.,
$$f(a) = m := \frac{f(1) + f(0)}{2}$$
for some $a > 1$.
We also know, by continuity, that the function achieves $m$ for some $b \in (0,1)$. Since $a > 1$ and $b \in (0,1)$, we have that $a \neq b$.
In summary, we have that $f(a) = f(b)$ for $a \neq b$; that is, $f$ is not one-to-one.

I really appreciate your help (and answer). Thank you very much.

@Nature9376 You're welcome! I was lost the first time that I saw this stuff, too. Eventually it falls into place. Keep working at it!

According to what I see from your comments, this seems to be a question on a course where they are just beginning to study continuity. This may be debatable, but probably whoever suggested this exercise is trying for you to "convince yourself" of the truth of the statement before actually giving a proof (which gives some context into the hint they give you). So let us do that first.
The statement says that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)}$, so take a piece of paper, draw a cartesian plane, and mark any point you like over the $y$-axis. That point is our $\left(0,f\left(0\right)\right)$; that is, the function crosses the $y$-axis at $y=f\left(0\right)$.
Now draw a horizontal line passing through that point. Since $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)}$, you know that this line is an asymptote (if you don't know the meaning of the word, just imagine that the graph of your function is getting arbitrarily closer to this horizontal line the further you look rightwards).
Now, remember what one-to-one means visually: it means that everytime you draw ANY horizontal line, this line touches the graph at AT MOST one point. Now do the mental experiment: can you imagine the graph of any CONTINUOUS satisfying all of these three properties?

It passes through a specific point of the $y$-axis.
When going rightwards, it gets arbitrarily close to the horizontal line passing through that same point.
No horizontal line touches the graph more than once.

You can't, right? That should give you a very strong intuition that what the exercise wants you to prove is true. So it is just a matter of doing all that in a more formal way, which we will do now, but observe how sometimes beginning with a visual intuition helps a lot to figure out a "formal proof" that maybe (when you're not very experienced) seems like fallen from heaven without any motivation.
So let us now perform the formal proof:
You know that limits when $x\to\infty$ have some formal definition having to do with the famous $M$-$\varepsilon$, correct? "For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $M>0$ such that for all $x>M$...".
Well, in exercises like these, the first thing you must always think about is how to choose an "appropriate" $\varepsilon>0$ to apply the definition.
In our case, of course no constant function is one-to-one, so we can safely disregard that possibility. So, assuming $f$ is non-constant, that means that there exists $c\in\left(0,\infty\right)$ such that $f\left(c\right)\neq f\left(0\right)$. Therefore we have a strictly positive number $\left|f\left(c\right)-f\left(0\right)\right|>0$. There seems to be no other obvious way to construct a positive number from the statement, so let us set $\varepsilon=\left |f\left(c\right)-f\left(0\right)\right |$. Applying the formal definition of $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)}$, we get that there exists $M>0$ such that $\left |f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right |<\varepsilon=\left |f\left(c\right)-f\left(0\right)\right |$ for all $x\in\left(M,\infty\right)$. In particular, if we fix some $x$ such that $x>M$ and also $x>c$ (you will see why I impose this last condition in a moment), then we can conclude that we have found some $x>c$ such that $\left |f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right |<\left |f\left(c\right)-f\left(0\right)\right |$
I leave you as an exercise to prove that the inequality $\left |f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right |<\left |f\left(c\right)-f\left(0\right)\right |$ implies that $f\left(x\right)$ is in between $f\left(0\right)$ and $f\left(c\right)$ (just split into the two cases $f\left(0\right)>f\left(c\right)$ and $f\left(
c\right)>f\left(0\right)$ and you'll be able to see it for yourself).
And now is where Bolzano's theorem comes into the picture: since $f\left(x\right)$ is a number that is in between $f\left(0\right)$ and $f\left(c\right)$, there must exist some $r\in\left(0,c\right)$ such that $f\left(r\right)=f\left(x\right)$. Moreover, we cannot have $r=x$ because $r<c<x$ (do you see now why I chose to impose also the condition $x>c$ in my choice of $x$?). There you are! This proves that the function is not one-to-one.

Wow, thank you so much for the detailed explanation on how to approach this kind of questions. I was indeed missing that.
Of course, I also thank you in general for the answer.

Solution (a)
Let $f$ be non constant. Let $x_1>0$ be a point such that $f(x_1)\neq f(0).$ WLOG we may assume that $f(x_1)>0.$ There is $x_2>x_1$ such that $f(x_2)<f(x_1).$
Consider the function $$g(x)=f(x)-f(x_1+ax),\quad a={x_2\over x_1}-1>0 $$ Then $g(0)=f(0)-f(x_1)<0$ and $g(x_1)=f(x_1)-f(x_2)>0.$ By the intermediate value theorem the function $g$ vanishes at some point in $(0,x_1),$ which gives the conclusion.
Solution (b)
Assume by contradiction that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ for any $x\neq y.$ By the intermediate value theorem the function $f(x) $ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. In the first case $f(1)>f(0).$ Thus $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\ge f(1)>f(0),$ which gives a contradiction. The second case can be reduced to the first one by considering $-f(x).$

Thank you very much.
